# Sencha Architect creates ViewModel and ViewController Automaticly

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, sencha-architect

I am working on **Sencha Architect** and following [this video](https://vimeo.com/59699981) which made by Sencha dev-team to walks around basics of application.

I got errors when i run the project and later figure out that somehow **Sencha Architect** created 'ViewModel' and 'ViewController' automatically.

Why could be? or is there any setting in application to block?

Here is a sample folder structure of 'View'. Files with '(*)' symbol not created by me..

```
view/
.. TicketDataView.js
.. TicketDataViewViewController.js (*)
.. TicketDataViewViewModel.js (*)
.. TicketPanel.js
.. TicketPanelViewController.js (*)
.. TicketPanelViewModel.js (*)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and i overcome on this situation with deleting 'ViewModel' and 'ViewController' files yet in Sencha Architect:

- On '**Project Inspector**' zone, clicked on 'TicketDataView' and it shows related items such as 'TicketDataViewViewModel' and 'TicketDataViewViewController'.
- Just right-click to see 'Delete' button and deleted those unnecessary files. So the *app.js* and *metadata/Application.js* files updated as well...

As well as changed the **Project Settings**:

- General> Overwrite index file on save: unchecked (leave blank)
- Framework> Build Tools: Disabled

Then saved the project and opened *index.html* and changed script tags for ext-all.js, theme.js and link tag for theme.css to [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/extjs)' library.  Sencha CDN links not working! so imported cdnjs instead of it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the video is four years old. Back then, the newest version of ExtJS was 4.x, and the MVVM model, which uses ViewModels and ViewControllers, was not available. With 5.x, released three years ago, the superior MVVM development model was introduced, so Sencha Architect assumes that in 2017, you always want to write MVVM instead of MVC. By the way, you will stumble over more outdated documentation along your steep journey trying to master ExtJS.

That said, you should make a new question including your code and error message to get help with your actual problem.

Comment: You are completely right about "old stuffs!" but unfortunately i couldn't find any new dated Architect tutorial -at least free one-. However thanks for your advice and reply.